# ngBootstrap Modal is not showing unless after second click

Tags: javascript, css, angular, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I have created a modal component called `ImportCardModalComponent`. 
This component must be opened if the login is failed. like follows:

```
this.authSerivce.logInRegular(this.model).then(result => {
      console.log(result);
    }, error => {
      var importModal = this.modalService.open(ImportCardModalComponent);

    });
```

The issue is that the dialog doesn't appear unless I click the button on screen twice and fire the service two times. 
The first time I click the button, DOM elements are added successfully but without css `class` in `<ngb-modal-backdrop> and <ngb-modal-window>`. As shown below. 
[image: The classes are not defined]
The second time I click on the button, the `classes` are showing correctly. As show below: [image]

The modal MUST have `class ="modal-backdrop fade show"` in backdrop element. As well as `class="modal fade show d-block"` in window element.

I tried to use the modalService with `NgbModalOptions` `backdropClass` and `windowClass` without any success to work from first time.

If I move the open modal service outside the reject callback, it works fine.

Any Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this `var importModal = this.modalService.open(ImportCardModalComponent);` is fired when user failed login? I think it will only fire if you have error.

Comment: try using Subscribe instead of then and see what you get, would also drop a console log in the error section to check when the first request gets to the error section.

Comment: Hi Maihan, Yes I'm sure it is fired. Because DOM elements are added correctly, and If I change the DOM elements using chrome developer console, The modal is shown.

Comment: Hi dince, I cannot use subscribe, because logInRegular is a chain of promises that call many web servers and end points and return one final Promise. but I will try

Comment: @NadeemKhoury check this https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/

Comment: Easiest would be to add component in the model `<my-model></my-model>` and bind a variable to it. Default `false` and when user login failed `true` to display.

Answer (score 11):

One way is to manually trigger change detection after modal service call.

Get the reference of `ApplicationRef`

```
constructor(private appRef: ApplicationRef,...){}
```

and then invoke change detection:

```
this.authSerivce.logInRegular(this.model).then(result => {
      console.log(result);
    }, error => {
      var importModal = this.modalService.open(ImportCardModalComponent);
      this.appRef.tick();
    });
```

Comment: This worked like a charm for me with angular 10. Make sure in the head of the component file you add    `  import { ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core `

Answer (score 0):

You can force Angular change detection by running you code inside ngZone

```
import { NgZone } from "@angular/core";
```

...

```
constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone){}
```

...

```
this._ngZone.run(() => this.modalService.open(ImportCardModalComponent));
```